# Twitter's Facebook connect behaves inconsistently

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Twitter's native Facebook connect app to work.  It works one day, doesn't work the next, and I find myself wasting hours trying to get everything to sync.

Does this app just not work?

Any other suggestions to reliably send tweets to FB Pages automatically?

Comment: Related question: [Twitter no longer posts to Facebook page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43597/354)

Comment: Related question: [Sending Tweets to a Facebook Page not working](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44656/354)

Comment: Related question; [Twitter not posting to Facebook page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24628/354)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of other ways to get tweets sent automatically to Facebook, either to your own timeline or to a page.

I used to use IFTTT. There are a bunch of recipes for this, such as [this one](https://ifttt.com/recipes/164927-when-i-tweet-it-then-feeds-to-my-facebook-fan-page).

One caveat: You can only have one Facebook Page (and I think one Twitter account) configured for an IFTTT account. If you've got multiple Facebook pages you'll need multiple IFTTT accounts.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot. I'm setting up a PBN so I do have multiple sites that I'll need to use this for.